# Prove that $\mathbf{R} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{N^2} : x \ge y \}$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

#### For the binary relation R over $\mathbb{N}$ described below,

#### establish whether R is a reflexive, symmetric or transitive relation.

#### $\mathbf{R} = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{N^2} : x \ge y \}$

How can I prove that?

#### my try:

$$
\text{reflexive}: x \ge x \ \text{(true)}\\
\text{symmetric}: x \ge y \iff y\ge x \ \text{(??That's not true)} \\
\text{transitive}: x \ge y, \ y \ge z \implies x \ge z \ \text{(true)}
$$

symmetric propriety doesn't seem true if $x \neq y$.

Comment: Symmetric property does not hold as you pointed out. However, you maybe confused 'equivalence relation' with 'order relation'?

Comment: @Senna no, the actual exercise ask to prove reflexive, symmetric, and transitive propriety, so it should be a relation of equivalence. I going to edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Have you defined $\geq$ differently? Otherwise, this seems like a typo.

Comment: I'm afraid it is a typo, unless $\leq$ means something different from the usual order of natural numbers.

Comment: @Zuy Excuse me, I didn't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: It‘s „whether“, not „that“.

Comment: To disprove symmetric, simply consider $x=2,y=1$. One counterexample is enough

Comment: It is a total order relation not an equivalence relation

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen and so is not actually a relation of equivalence?

Comment: @LorisSimonetti it is not an equivalence relation! If it does not hold the symmetric property it cannnot be an eqauivalence relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an equivalence relation because, as you see in the comments, symmetry fails (just pick the point $(2,1)$). The $\ge$ relation on, say, the natural numbers is, instead, satisfying the [antisymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation) property.